# How to enable other public user to open up a firefox from your server in WAMP

Tags: php, apache, laravel, server, wamp

I am using laravel 5.2 to create an API with my windows server, my API will open up a firefox browser.

When I am using "php artisan serve" in cmd to open 8000 port, the API works fine.

But when I setup virtual host in httpd.conf it can't open up the firefox, and return me "browser did not respond before timeout".

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/test/public/"
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/test/public/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have try to set up firewall to allow access all connection by port 80, but it still does not work for me.